# Problemas me toma la consulta como Alerta Injection SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server

De antemano gracias por responder.

El problema es que al ejecutarse la siguiente consulta me sale una alerta de *injection SQL*.

```
\!/ ALERTA !!!!!

[09 Aug 2016 10:45:30] <br>
TIPO: SQL INJECTION-INTERNO <br>
URL ATAQUE: /gci//workflowgestion/workflowgestion.php <br>
CAMPO: sql <br>
ATAQUE: UPDATE detalleplannorma SET dtleplnanrma_observacion = ('FLUJO ENVIADO - ' + COALESCE(dtleplnanrma_observacion, '') ) <br>
, wrkogsto_id = #wrkogsto_id# WHERE dtleplnanrma_id = 404 <br>
DESCRIPCION: update detalleplannorma set dtleplnanrma_observacion =|||||dtleplnanrma_observacion <br>
IP: ::1 <br>
SERVER-NAME: localhost <br>
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Esta es la función que se ejecuta cuando doy clic para actualizar; pienso que es porque se envía el SQL a través de la URL, aunque no estoy seguro.
Les agradecería mucho.

```
<script>
                $(function(){ <br>

                    $("#workflow").click(function(){ <br>

gestionar_workflow ('<?=$PATH_GCI?>/workflowgestion/workflowgestion.php', '<?=$wrko_id?>', '<?=$asunto_workflow?>', '<?=$crgo_id?>', '<?=$sql_workflow?>', 'GCI', '<?=$wrkogsto_id?>', 'MODAL', '');
<br>
    $('body').on('dialogclose', '#dialog-window-gci-workflow', function(){
<br>
                            window.open('<?=$window_open_after?>');
                            <br>
                            $('#dialog-window-gci').on('dialogclose',
<br> function(){ 
            <br>                    $('body').find('table[id^="grid_modulo_"]').each(function(){
<br>
                                    $(this).trigger('reloadGrid');
<br>
                                });
<br>
                            });
<br>
                        });
<br>
                    });
<br>
                }); 
<br>
            </script>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo usar procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: Se envía el sql a través de una url?? Eso es peligrosisimo. Lee un poco sobre ataques (sql injection attack, especialmente)

Comment: Si eso es lo que he estado mirando aunque todavia no lo he podido solucionar.

Answer (score 2):

Las sentencias SQL no deben ser concatenación de strings, pues un atancante puede inyectar sentencias en la variable dtleplnanrma_observacion.
Para un reemplazo seguro debes utilizar parametros, según el driver/base de datos para que tu sentencia quede algo parecido a:

```
UPDATE detalleplannorma SET dtleplnanrma_observacion = 'FLUJO ENVIADO - ' + COALESCE(?, '')
```

Comment: Lo intentare. Gracias